# Java: Process Builder creating zombies

Tags: java, process

Am I doing anything wrong here?  Not handling a stream properly?

I run a process here (specifically: `mvn exec:java`) and the process does not terminate, even if I run `p.killForcibly()`.

If I go to the commandline and attempt a `taskkill /F /PID` on the pid I get from the flapdoodle library, I get "access denied" and the process lives on.

```
try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
            log.createNewFile();
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            builder.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));

            final Process p = builder.directory(dir).start();

            Long pid = de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Processes.processId(p);
            System.out.println("pid: " + pid);

            class InnerRunner implements Runnable {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        int rc = p.waitFor();
                        if (callback != null)
                            callback.onComplete(rc);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("process was interuppted", ie);
                    }
                }
            }
            Thread t = new Thread(new InnerRunner());
            return p;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException      ("Failed to run process: " + commands + ".  Ran it in: " + dir.getAbsolutePath(), ioe); 
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new RuntimeException("err", t);
        }
Thread t = new Thread(new InnerRunner());
```

A possible clue: the output log file I redirect the processes output to is still being held open by the process.  I can't delete it until I kill the process off in task manager.

Comment: I’m not sure if this is the cause, but you are never calling `t.start()`.  You create a Thread but it never runs.

Comment: Your also not reading the process's output which sometimes cause the process to stall

Comment: Starting a Process does not start a Thread object.  They are two entirely disparate methods which happen to have the same signature.

Comment: @VGR Gah, that was a bad cut and paste... fixed it, thanks.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I call `redirectOutput()`, is there more I need to do?

Comment: Normally I read the process's `InputStream` (just discarding the results if I don't need them), not sure how that would work with redirection

Comment: @MadProgrammer That actually helped, I wrapped it in a reader and did ` while ((lineRead = br.readLine()) != null) {`.  Help me understand this... is this reading lines from whatever is piped into the inputstream that the process will read from?  IE, the stdin?